# What do i set the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS. When an element name is used many times

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to post images with cURL in PHP using multipart/form-data header.

I want to know what setting the "CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS" for curl.

I want to send like this value for server.

The element name has been used many times.

```
-----------------------------7e21b0029071a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="updates[]"

1
-----------------------------7e21b0029071a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="set_images[]"

1
-----------------------------7e21b0029071a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="updates[]"

1
-----------------------------7e21b0029071a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="set_images[]"

1
-----------------------------7e21b0029071a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="images[]"; filename="1.JPG"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

** raw image data **
-----------------------------7e21b0029071a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="images[]"; filename="2.JPG"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

** raw image data **
-----------------------------7e21b0029071a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="images[]"; filename="3.JPG"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

** raw image data *
-----------------------------7e21b0029071a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="images[]"; filename="4.JPG"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

** raw image data **
-----------------------------7e21b0029071a--
```

I was teryed this option.

it was not work.

```
$data = array(
    'updates[0]' => '1',
    'set_images[0]' => '1',
    'updates[1]' => '1',
    'set_images[1]' => '1',
    'updates[2]' => '1',
    'set_images[2]' => '1',
    'updates[3]' => '1',
    'set_images[3]' => '1',
    'images[0]' => new CURLFile('1.JPG'),
    'images[1]' => new CURLFile('2.JPG'),
    'images[2]' => new CURLFile('3.JPG'),
    'images[3]' => new CURLFile('4.JPG'),
);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

Is it impossible to send the raw data of the first example?

Comment: Prefill the array names with numeric indexes.

Comment: `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` can be an array representing your post data, for the files you would use instances of [CURLFile](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php).

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
After all, I solved it by a method not using curl.